# Proof of right continuity of right derivative of convex functions?is there anything wrong?

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

[image: orginal proposition]

Here is my proof for (e): for $x\in int(I)$, let
$s^+ (x, t) = \frac{f (x + t) - f (x)}{t} ; s^- (x, t) = \frac{f (x) - f (x
   - t)}{t}$,
then $f^+ (x) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} s^+ (x, t)$.

Since $s^+ (x, t) = s^- (x + t, t) \leqslant f^+ (x + t)$, it holds that $f^+
(x) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} s^+ (x, t) \leqslant \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} f^+
(x + t)$.

For the inverse inequality, note that :
$f^+ (x + t) = \lim_{\beta \rightarrow 0} s^+ (x + t, \beta) \leqslant s^+
   (x + t, t) = 2 s^+ (x + 2 t) - s^+ (x + t)$.

Thus
$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} f^+ (x + t) \leqslant \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} (2 s^+
   (x + 2 t) - s^+ (x + t)) = f^+ (x)$.

Combine above two inequalities, we get $f^+$ is right continues in $int(I)$.

But it seems that my proof automatically extends to the boundaries when $a\in I$, however i know it's not true.

A case is that for some continues convex function $f$ on $[a,b]$,let $g(x)=f(x)$ when $x \in (a,b]$ and $g(a)=f(a)+1$.  Then $g$ is convex but $g^+(a)=-\infty$.

What`wrong with my proof? Did i miss anything?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.